# What technologies use to solve distributed transactions in real operating env(such as Netflix Inc.)?

Tags: spring, architecture, transactions, axon, saga

I'm converting the Monolith spring project to MSA environment.
But, I faced the issue of distributed transaction.

I know there are two ways to solve distributed transaction: `2pc commit` and `saga`.

I tried to solve it with **Saga pattern of Axon framework.**

However, the Saga feature of the Axon Framework, which focuses on DDD, EventSourcing, and CQRS, did not appear to be very good. (**I only need Saga pattern** because it is impossible to apply DDD concept right now.)

In many companies that have well-established MSA environments(such as Netflix), **what technology (not abstract technology) is being used to solve distributed transactions?**

Comment: They don't and 2pc commit or XA will not solve your issues. You need a saga or build upon the fact that you have eventual consistency in your architecture.

Answer (score 2):

[temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source platform is used by many companies (including Netflix and [Coinbase](https://docs.temporal.io/blog/reliable-crypto-transactions-at-coinbase)) to guarantee the execution of business processes as well as appropriate compensations. SAGA is also directly supported.

Here is the snippet from the SAGA [sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/bookingsaga/TripBookingWorkflowImpl.java):

```java
    Saga saga = new Saga(sagaOptions);
    try {
      String carReservationID = activities.reserveCar(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelCar, carReservationID, name);

      String hotelReservationID = activities.bookHotel(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelHotel, hotelReservationID, name);

      String flightReservationID = activities.bookFlight(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelFlight, flightReservationID, name);
    } catch (ActivityFailure e) {
      saga.compensate();
      throw e;
    }
```